# How to do database queries with Drupal 7 without coding?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-modules

My professor recently gave my class an assignment and I need help finding the tools to do so.

We have a database of tables (Customer, Payment, Order, etc.) and I need to use Drupal 7 to allow users to see customer's info, view customer data (i.e. payment history), or edit customer information. This would involve select statements, aggregate clauses, joins, etc. It would also involve forms to input customer name/information.

Here is the catch: I am not allowed to write any code. That means no API, no SQL queries, and no PHP. I am only allowed to use ready-built modules.

So my questions is: What module(s) should I use, and how do I use them?

I know the view is a good place to start, but the default options of view are for content. I have tables on a database, not content. Also from what I understand, custom queries of view require coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

http://drupal.org/project/data

If it integrates with the Views module properly, then you won't be required to do any hand-coding to make a View which queries your tables.

(Disclaimer: I haven't actually used it)